# Jquery validation of string and date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to validate three input field   http://jsfiddle.net/HSKAT/20/

1. only add date

Is there any **regular expression for validating** this.. i dont want to use the plugins

```
$('.validate-string').change(function (e) {
    var valid_str = $(this).val();
    ........ 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to validate string and number.. but for date you have define which format you want, kindly check below code number and string

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.validate-string').change(function (e) {
            var valid_str = $(this).val();
           var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
            if (regex.test(valid_str)) {
                alert("Valid");
            } else {
                alert("Invalid");
            }

        });
         $('.validate-number').change(function (e) {
            var valid_num = $(this).val();
             if(!valid_num.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/)){
             alert("Only numbers allow");
                 return false;
             }

        });
       $('.validate-date').change(function (e) {
        var valid_date = $(this).val();
//yyyy-mm-dd
       var filter = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;

if(filter.test(valid_date))

 alert("Date");

else

 alert("Not date");
    });
});
    });
```

Comment: yes date is not working because you have not define which date format you want to validate. kindly define me which pattern or format for date you want..

Comment: i want all the patterns that means give data is date or not.. i am tried the following http://jsfiddle.net/HSKAT/23/ but always get "Not Date"

Comment: Try this pattern
//yyyy-mm-dd
 var filter = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;

Comment: What are the regular expresion for other date format

Comment: you can play with 
filter = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;
and also there are many methods to get different formats, it depends on you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use plugins, regex would be your best bet.
Use this regex to match numbers: `^[0-9]*$`
and for strings (words) use: `^[a-zA-Z]*$`

Use `test()` to test the regex. [More info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: no i want to do this using jquery.. some time i am not using input types

Answer (score 0):

Try to check moment js for validation of time or date.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: i cant use any plugins

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#txtDate').blur(function() {

   if(validateDate('txtDate'))

   {

      alert('Date is valid');

   }

   else

  {

      alert('Invalid Date!!!');

  }

  });

  });



//Functions Starts

function validateDate(txtDate){

var txtVal = document.getElementById(txtDate).value;

var filter = new RegExp("(0[123456789]|10|11|12)([/])([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])");

if(filter.test(txtVal))

  return true;

else

 return false;

} ​
```

Comment: please look my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HSKAT/23/

Comment: hi parvathi please try to look on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/_goi/gDAjy/

Comment: hi parvathi how is it?

Comment: validate only dd/mm/yyyy format and 13/13/2014 is also tru!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function validateDate(inputVal)
    {

        var dateReg = /^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]      {1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$/;
        return dateReg.test(inputVal);
    }
```

Comment: try this regex hope this fine.